# Consulta de um usuário de um programa em php a banco de dados por um período especificado pelo mesmo

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho um banco de dados em phpmyadmin. Um dos campos é "Data" no formato "date".Preciso fazer uma pergunta ao usuário do banco de dados, através de php, para que através do "imput" sejam listados os dados do banco no período especificado, por exemplo "2015-10-01 a 2015-10-31"?pelo usuário.

Comment: O que você já fez? Em que parte está a sua dúvida?

Comment: Olá Eduardo. Preparo um peq. programa em php para controle de finanças domésticas.Criei um banco de dados e um dos campos é a data do lançamento da despesa. O programa precisa listar as despesas num determinado período. Sei fazer isto no banco de dados phpmyadmin usando sql. Mas gostaria de fazer esta consulta através do programa, usando linguagem php. O usuário do programa digitaria a data inicial e a data final da pesquisa e com esta informação o programa listaria as despesas do período especificado. O que não estou conseguindo fazer é usar as datas de entrada em php para listar as despesas